# Property 'menuInfo' does not exist on type 'ModeContextType | undefined'. TS2339

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying do use context with React hook with typescript. I have no idea where did I do wrong.

```
export interface IPayload {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  [key: string]: any;
}

export interface ModeContextType {
  menuInfo: IPayload;
  modeData: IPayload;
  currentModeCode: number;
  setCurrentModeCode: (arg0: string) => void;
}

export const ModeContext = createContext<ModeContextType | undefined>(undefined);
```

```
  const modeContextValue = {
    menuInfo: menuInfo,
    modeData: modeData,
    currentModeCode: currentModeCode,
    setCurrentModeCode: setCurrentModeCode,
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ModeContext.Provider value={modeContextValue}>
        <Header currentModeCode={currentModeCode} />
        <div className="thumbnail-block" ref={thumbnailBlock}>
          {listOfThumbnails}
        </div>
        <div id="detail-set-block">
          <DetailCampaign key={currentCampaignCode} info={currentCampaign} />
        </div>
        <div className="clearfix">
          <button id="see-all" type="button" className="btn btn-dark">
            {t("top.see_all_product_at_this_fair")}
          </button>
        </div>
        <Category />
      </ModeContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
```

In the child component, I use `useContext` as follow

```
function Category(): JSX.Element {
  const { menuInfo, modeData, currentModeCode, setCurrentModeCode } = useContext(ModeContext);
```

the error is

```
Property 'menuInfo' does not exist on type 'ModeContextType | undefined'.  TS2339

     6 | 
     7 | function Category(): JSX.Element {
  >  8 |   const { menuInfo, modeData, currentModeCode, setCurrentModeCode } = useContext(ModeContext);
       |           ^
     9 |   // const modeData = getMode(menuInfo);
    10 |   const listOfModes = Object.entries(modeData).map(([modeCode, modeInfo]) => {
    11 |     return (
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've typed your context as `ModeContextType | undefined`, and it has a default value of `undefined`. Which means that you can't assume that the properties that you are destructuring actually exist.

The error you're getting is because `menuInfo` does not exist on all members of that union type, because of those members is `undefined`.

So you may need to do something like:

```
const modeContextValue = useContext(ModeContext);
if (modeContextValue) {
  { menuInfo, modeData, currentModeCode, setCurrentModeCode } = modeContextValue
  // other code that can run when modeContextValue has a value.
}
```

---

Or perhaps remove `undefined` from the context type and provide a full set of defaults:

```
export const ModeContext = createContext<ModeContextType>({
  menuInfo: {},
  modeData: {},
  currentModeCode: 0,
  setCurrentModeCode: () => undefined,
});
```